# Get the latest data from api in androd (java)

Tags: java, android, json, api

hi I want to get the latest data from this API using java in android studio
API link https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/usa
the API content like below data so I need to know how to fetch the latest data from it

```
[
   {
      "ID":"f3a22636-93a7-4ea8-8cee-2f6cd7ed73f4",
      "Country":"United States of America",
      "CountryCode":"US",
      "Province":"Diamond Princess",
      "City":"",
      "CityCode":"",
      "Lat":"35.44",
      "Lon":"139.64",
      "Confirmed":49,
      "Deaths":0,
      "Recovered":0,
      "Active":49,
      "Date":"2020-08-04T00:00:00Z"
   },
   {
      "ID":"021c00b1-ba8e-4e0d-95fa-7492c5c38191",
      "Country":"United States of America",
      "CountryCode":"US",
      "Province":"South Dakota",
      "City":"",
      "CityCode":"",
      "Lat":"44.3",
      "Lon":"-99.44",
      "Confirmed":104512,
      "Deaths":1614,
      "Recovered":0,
      "Active":102898,
      "Date":"2021-01-14T00:00:00Z"
   },
   {
      "ID":"02c792d7-a931-4449-b14e-d156aeef0a5a",
      "Country":"United States of America",
      "CountryCode":"US",
      "Province":"Maine",
      "City":"",
      "CityCode":"",
      "Lat":"44.69",
      "Lon":"-69.38",
      "Confirmed":31958,
      "Deaths":461,
      "Recovered":0,
      "Active":31497,
      "Date":"2021-01-14T00:00:00Z"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to extract data from api urls in Android apps.

Comment: how? please can you explain it with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use OkHTTP library. Here is an example snippet:

```
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "app_key=whatever");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://app.inyek.com/app_api/api_extra/all_order.php")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("key", "whatever")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("Postman-Token", "whatever")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```